# How do I remove the title from a Kcross plot?

Tags: r, spatstat

I'd like to plot a Kcross() plot in R and I'm having trouble removing main. I've tried `main=""`, `main=NULL` and adjusting the `mar=c()` so it won't show the title, but none of that seems to be working properly. The problem pops up when I'm working with Kcross(), Jcross(), etc., on any other plot `main=""` works just fine. Any ideas?

```
kfunkcrossA <- alltypes(combinedA,Kcross,correction="border")

pdf(file = paste0(resultspath,var,"/kfunkcross",var,".pdf"),width = 5, height=3, family="CM Roman")
par(mar=c(2,2,2,2))
plot(kfunkcrossA,.-r~r,main=NULL)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually estimating Kcross for all combinations of types in your data.
The result of `alltypes()` is an object of class `fasp` (Function Arrays for
Spatial Patterns). When you use the generic `plot()` function it dispatches
to `plot.fasp()`. The help file for `plot.fasp()` tells you that the correct
argument name is `title`. In lack of your data is an example with built-in
data:

```r
library(spatstat)
#> Loading required package: spatstat.data
#> Loading required package: spatstat.geom
#> spatstat.geom 2.1-0.002
#> Loading required package: spatstat.core
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> Loading required package: rpart
#> spatstat.core 2.1-2.004
#> Loading required package: spatstat.linnet
#> spatstat.linnet 2.1-1.002
#> 
#> spatstat 2.1-0       (nickname: 'Comedic violence') 
#> For an introduction to spatstat, type 'beginner'
combinedA <- amacrine # Use built-in data
kfunkcrossA <- alltypes(combinedA, Kcross, correction="border")
class(kfunkcrossA) # Class fasp
#> [1] "fasp"
plot(kfunkcrossA, .-r~r, title="") # Calling plot.fasp()
```

[image]